# Using a variable to set the x point of a line

Tags: pine-script

How can I draw a line using one of my variables as x point?
For example: variable =  (an engulfing which close under an ema)

If I write: `line.new(x1=variable....)` The script gives me error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) which should explain that it is better to say what the error is than just saying that you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the variable candle is a boolean?

`line.new()` function requires a **bar_index** or **timestamp** for the `x` argument.

The example below connects 2 latest bearish Engulfing candle's closes with a red line using the ta.valuewhen() built-in function.
*using the built-in source code for the engulfing candle

```
//@version=5
indicator("Engulfing - Bearish", shorttitle = "Engulfing - Bear", overlay=true)

C_DownTrend = true
C_UpTrend = true
var trendRule1 = "SMA50"
var trendRule2 = "SMA50, SMA200"
var trendRule = input.string(trendRule1, "Detect Trend Based On", options=[trendRule1, trendRule2, "No detection"])

if trendRule == trendRule1
    priceAvg = ta.sma(close, 50)
    C_DownTrend := close < priceAvg
    C_UpTrend := close > priceAvg

if trendRule == trendRule2
    sma200 = ta.sma(close, 200)
    sma50 = ta.sma(close, 50)
    C_DownTrend := close < sma50 and sma50 < sma200
    C_UpTrend := close > sma50 and sma50 > sma200
C_Len = 14 // ta.ema depth for bodyAvg
C_ShadowPercent = 5.0 // size of shadows
C_ShadowEqualsPercent = 100.0
C_DojiBodyPercent = 5.0
C_Factor = 2.0 // shows the number of times the shadow dominates the candlestick body

C_BodyHi = math.max(close, open)
C_BodyLo = math.min(close, open)
C_Body = C_BodyHi - C_BodyLo
C_BodyAvg = ta.ema(C_Body, C_Len)
C_SmallBody = C_Body < C_BodyAvg
C_LongBody = C_Body > C_BodyAvg
C_UpShadow = high - C_BodyHi
C_DnShadow = C_BodyLo - low
C_HasUpShadow = C_UpShadow > C_ShadowPercent / 100 * C_Body
C_HasDnShadow = C_DnShadow > C_ShadowPercent / 100 * C_Body
C_WhiteBody = open < close
C_BlackBody = open > close
C_Range = high-low
C_IsInsideBar = C_BodyHi[1] > C_BodyHi and C_BodyLo[1] < C_BodyLo
C_BodyMiddle = C_Body / 2 + C_BodyLo
C_ShadowEquals = C_UpShadow == C_DnShadow or (math.abs(C_UpShadow - C_DnShadow) / C_DnShadow * 100) < C_ShadowEqualsPercent and (math.abs(C_DnShadow - C_UpShadow) / C_UpShadow * 100) < C_ShadowEqualsPercent
C_IsDojiBody = C_Range > 0 and C_Body <= C_Range * C_DojiBodyPercent / 100
C_Doji = C_IsDojiBody and C_ShadowEquals

patternLabelPosLow = low - (ta.atr(30) * 0.6)
patternLabelPosHigh = high + (ta.atr(30) * 0.6)

label_color_bearish = input(color.red, "Label Color Bearish")
C_EngulfingBearishNumberOfCandles = 2
C_EngulfingBearish = C_UpTrend and C_BlackBody and C_LongBody and C_WhiteBody[1] and C_SmallBody[1] and close <= open[1] and open >= close[1] and ( close < open[1] or open > close[1] )
alertcondition(C_EngulfingBearish, title = "New pattern detected", message = "New Engulfing – Bearish pattern detected")
if C_EngulfingBearish
    var ttBearishEngulfing = "Engulfing\nAt the end of a given uptrend, a reversal pattern will most likely appear. During the first day, this candlestick pattern uses a small body. It is then followed by a day where the candle body fully overtakes the body from the day before it and closes in the trend’s opposite direction. Although similar to the outside reversal chart pattern, it is not essential for this pattern to fully overtake the range (high to low), rather only the open and the close."
    label.new(bar_index, patternLabelPosHigh, text="BE", style=label.style_label_down, color = label_color_bearish, textcolor=color.white, tooltip = ttBearishEngulfing)
bgcolor(ta.highest(C_EngulfingBearish?1:0, C_EngulfingBearishNumberOfCandles)!=0 ? color.new(color.red, 90) : na, offset=-(C_EngulfingBearishNumberOfCandles-1))

// -----
// line connects closing values of the 2 latest engulfing candles
var line line1 = line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.red) 
line.set_xy1(line1, ta.valuewhen(C_EngulfingBearish, bar_index, 0), ta.valuewhen(C_EngulfingBearish, close, 0))
line.set_xy2(line1, ta.valuewhen(C_EngulfingBearish, bar_index, 1), ta.valuewhen(C_EngulfingBearish, close, 1))
```

[image]

You can compare the values of the engulfing candle later using the built-in fixnan() function:

```
C_EngulfingBearishClose = fixnan(C_EngulfingBearish ? close : na)
C_EngulfingBearishTime = fixnan(C_EngulfingBearish ? time : na)
plot(C_EngulfingBearishClose)
bgcolor(C_EngulfingBearishTime == time ? color.purple : na)
```

[image]